# hacer request a servicio en ajax usando angular tambien

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Intento consumirlo de la siguiente manera

```
function listar( $scope, $http, cliente) {

    $http({
    method: "POST",
    data: cliente,
    url: "http://ver.moz.com.mx/movil//Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle" + cliente+'5000',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'dataType': 'json'
    }

    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.estados = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        var array = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        $scope.estados = JSON.parse(array);
    }, function error(response) {
        $scope.myerror = response.statusText;

    });

}
```

y me da por error

> bad request

Comment: El servicio que tratas de consumir, esta definido por SOAP, deberías pasarle la definición xml del metodo y argumentos que necesitas llamar.

Comment: Y por lo visto, el wsdl y el js deben estar publicados en el mismo dominio, puedes probar con este modulo de angular haber si te sirve https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

Comment: Emanuelle, el error esta en tu URL, esta mal escrita, la correcta deberia ser `http://ver.moz.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle` mas tus parametros